# Cannot dynamic cast when using dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, dynamic-cast

Why does this code not work?

```
std::shared_ptr<Event> e = ep->pop();
std::shared_ptr<TrackerEvent> t;

t = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<TrackerEvent>(e);
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:386: error: cannot dynamic_cast '(& __r)->std::shared_ptr<Event>::<anonymous>.std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::get [with _Tp = Event, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]()' (of type 'class Event*') to type 'class TrackerEvent*' (source type is not polymorphic)
```

`TrackerEvent` inherits from `Event` so I guess the problem is that I can't cast in this direction. But `ep->pop()` might either return an object of type `Event` or `TrackerEvent`. And I was hoping that when I try to cast it to `TrackerEvent` and it returns `NULL` I would know whether I have an `Event` or `TrackerEvent`...

How would I do that?

Comment: You need to have at least one virtual method to use dynmaic_cast.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler is telling you what is going on at the end of the message:

> (source type is not polymorphic)

Your `Event` base class needs to have at least one `virtual` member function (i.e. be a *polymorphic type*) in order to allow dynamic casts. You could make the destructor of `Event` virtual:

```
class Event
{
public:
    virtual ~Event() { /* whatever goes here, or nothing... */ }
    // ...
};
```

Here is a [live example with polymorphic types](http://ideone.com/Hon1Gv), showing that the code compiles (removing the virtual destructor would cause a compilation error [similar to the one you are seeing](http://ideone.com/WXX6Fx)).

As correctly mentioned by [Luc Danton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374671/cannot-dynamic-cast-when-using-dynamic-ponter-cast/16374685?noredirect=1#comment23466560_16374685) in the comments, a defaulted version of a virtual destructor can be defined this way (if your compiler is C++11-compliant in this respect):

```
class Event
{
public:
    virtual ~Event() = default;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: @LucDanton: Right, I forgot to mention that. Edited, thank you

Answer (score 3):

To perform a `dynamic_cast`, the type you're casting from must be polymorphic. For this to be true, it must have or inherit some virtual members. Make sure `Event` has a virtual member function (at the very least, a virtual destructor).